# undefined method `executeScript' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Bridge:0x007ffd0fa16e90>

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`undefined method executeScript' for <Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Bridge:0x007ffd0fa16e90> Did you mean?  execute_script (NoMethodError)`

I'm getting this error on any line with `element.fire_event('onClick')`

Chrome version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)
ChromeDriver 2.24.417412
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16]

I'm using selenium-webdriver/page object.. I defined my element..
    `checkbox(:check_the_box, :id => 'checkboxid')`

then tried to execute a fire_event on it.. 
    `check_the_box_element.fire_event('onClick')`

then i receive the error above.

Answer (score 1):

> undefined method `executeScript' for # Did you mean? execute_script (NoMethodError)

Exception clearly states, It should be [`WebDriver#execute_script(script, *args)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver#execute_script-instance_method) instead

Comment: Whoops did not mean to hit enter.. I'm using selenium-webdriver/page object..

I defined my element..
checkbox(:check_the_box, :id => 'checkbox_id')

Comment: Hit enter again... -_- .. I'm new here

Whoops did not mean to hit enter.. I'm using selenium-webdriver/page object.. I defined my element.. checkbox(:check_the_box, :id => 'checkbox_id')  then tried to execute a fire_event on it.. check_the_box_element.fire_event('onClick')